# Is there any way to amplify Audio Manager maximum volume?

Tags: android

I'm working on a volume booster app where I needs to boost volume. I wants to know is there any way where I can increase/amplify volume of music from it's actual maximum volume?

Comment: Assuming the input is mastered already, you'll not raise the RMS by much - while this question shows little research - and also, the concept which shall be implemented seems unrealistic, at best. I'd not bother and simply by an USB headphones amplifier ... so how come, these products do even exist?

Comment: @MartinZeitler we can enhance volume loudness by LoudnessEnhacer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
fun boostLoudness(boost: Int) {
            val level = boost.toFloat() / 100.0f * 8000.0f
            loudness = LoudnessEnhancer(mediaPlayer!!.audioSessionId)
            if (loudness != null) {
                try {
                    loudness!!.setTargetGain(level.toInt())
                    loudness!!.enabled = true
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }
```